# System.ArgumentException - caption cannot be an empty string

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-core-3.1, argumentexception

I'm trying to load an existing solution in Visual Studio 2022. One of projects in this solution is in error :
[image]

A message appears at top of the main window :

```
Visual Studio ran into an uexpected problem with one or more projects. You may need to reload affected projects or the solution to prevent further problems.
```

There are the logs when I click on "Open log file" :

```
=====================
11/07/2023 15:01:43
LimitedFunctionality
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: 'caption' cannot be an empty string ("") or start with the null character.
Parameter name: caption
   at Microsoft.Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.GetDebuggerTargets(IPropertyPagesCatalog catalog, IImmutableDictionary`2 dynamicTargets)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.<LinkExternalInput>b__38_1(IProjectVersionedValue`1 bunch)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformBlockSlimSync.ProcessInputAsync(TInput input)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
<--- (Inner Exception #0) 
===================
11/07/2023 15:01:43
LimitedFunctionality
System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'DebugTargetsSubscriptionService: 59778726' closed because of an exception.
'caption' cannot be an empty string ("") or start with the null character.
Parameter name: caption
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: 'caption' cannot be an empty string ("") or start with the null character.
Parameter name: caption
   at Microsoft.Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.GetDebuggerTargets(IPropertyPagesCatalog catalog, IImmutableDictionary`2 dynamicTargets)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.<LinkExternalInput>b__38_1(IProjectVersionedValue`1 bunch)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformBlockSlimSync.ProcessInputAsync(TInput input)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
<--- (Inner Exception #0) 
===================
```

When I check the activity log, there are errors :

```
      <entry>
    <record>468</record>
    <time>2023/07/11 13:09:52.917</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>CPS</source>
    <description>CPS &apos;LimitedFunctionality&apos; in project &apos;C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj&apos; failure: System.ArgumentException: &apos;caption&apos; cannot be an empty string (&quot;&quot;) or start with the null character.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: caption  Call Stack:    at Microsoft.Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(String value, String parameterName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.GetDebuggerTargets(IPropertyPagesCatalog catalog, IImmutableDictionary`2 dynamicTargets)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.&lt;LinkExternalInput&gt;b__38_1(IProjectVersionedValue`1 bunch)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformBlockSlimSync.ProcessInputAsync(TInput input)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.&lt;ProcessInputQueueAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>469</record>
    <time>2023/07/11 13:09:52.917</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>CPS</source>
    <description>CPS &apos;LimitedFunctionality&apos; in project &apos;C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj&apos; failure: System.ArgumentException: &apos;caption&apos; cannot be an empty string (&quot;&quot;) or start with the null character.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: caption  Call Stack:    at Microsoft.Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(String value, String parameterName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.GetDebuggerTargets(IPropertyPagesCatalog catalog, IImmutableDictionary`2 dynamicTargets)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.DebugTargetsSubscriptionService.&lt;LinkExternalInput&gt;b__38_1(IProjectVersionedValue`1 bunch)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformBlockSlimSync.ProcessInputAsync(TInput input)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.&lt;ProcessInputQueueAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
```

...

```
  <entry>
    <record>569</record>
    <time>2023/07/11 13:10:23.379</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>A MEF Component threw an exception at runtime: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.&#x000D;&#x000A;Object name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory+RuntimeExportProvider+RuntimePartLifecycleTracker&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.ThrowIfDisposed()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.ConstructExportedValue(RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, PartLifecycleTracker partLifecycle, ReportFaultCallback faultCallback)</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>570</record>
    <time>2023/07/11 13:10:23.405</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>A MEF Component threw an exception at runtime: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.&#x000D;&#x000A;Object name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory+RuntimeExportProvider+RuntimePartLifecycleTracker&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.ThrowIfDisposed()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.ConstructExportedValue(RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, PartLifecycleTracker partLifecycle, ReportFaultCallback faultCallback)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetExportedValue(RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, Boolean lazy, PartLifecycleTracker&amp; partLifecycle)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.&lt;CreateValue&gt;b__11_0(RuntimeImport import)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.ConstructExportedValue(RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, PartLifecycleTracker partLifecycle, ReportFaultCallback faultCallback)</description>
  </entry>
```

I looked on Google for hours but don't find any tips about this error.

I already tried to remove .vs, bin, obj directories without any success.

Update : When I click on "Reload faulted project(s)", the error disappears because the project is not selected anymore. The error appears again only when I select the project. If I unload / reload the project (right-click), the error reappears because the project is still selected.

[image]

Comment: If you right click the erroneous project, is there an unload option? If so, try that and reload it

Comment: Same error appears after unloading / reloading

Answer (score 0):

open  'launchSettings.json' in 'Properties' folder in the project structure and set the name for the first index of the profiles array.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "[Set Name Here]": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:59006;http://localhost:59007"
    }
  }
}
```